# Create transaction in Typeorm vs Sequelize

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I was using Sequelize before and trying to migrate to typeorm for a new tool I am building. I create transaction in sequelize like the below

`const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();`

And will pass this transaction to the model methods like `model.create(params, {transaction})`.

With Typeorm I can only write this model creation wrapped inside the transaction method.

`getConnection().transaction(entityManager -> { modle.create(params)})`

Because of this restriction, I am not able to pass the transaction object to hooks which will be executed once the object is built.

Is there anyway in typeorm to create and pass the transaction object like how it is in sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

Typeorm by default doesn't support such transactions.

We can however use [typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked) package.